# What is this icon in the top bar of CIvilizations VI?

Tags: civilization-6, civilization-6-gathering-storm

Since I am on Xbox it's not letting me access the top bar to get the description. So I tried to find the meaning of the icon everywhere.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**This is new to the Civilization Gathering Storm expansion. It's called [Diplomatic Favor](https://civilization.fandom.com/wiki/Diplomatic_Favor_(Civ6)).**

> "It represents your state influence power before other leaders in the world and is used mainly in the World Congress."

It's a new resource that is a key part of winning the new Diplomatic Victory. It can be used to spend on the World Congress in votes, and it can also be traded to other civilizations in whole sums like gold can, but not at a per turn value.

> There are three main sources of Diplomatic Favor:
>
> - Governments
>
> Each type of government provides a number of points of Diplomatic Favor equal to its tier each turn. For example, Monarchy is a Tier 2 government and provides 2 points of Diplomatic Favor per turn, while Democracy, a Tier 3 government, provides 3 points per turn. This is the most reliable and steady source of Diplomatic Favor.
>
> - Suzerainty
>
> Being the Suzerain of any city-state provides +1 point/turn per city-state. It can be increased to 2 points/turn per city-state if you have the Országház Wonder. Of course, this trickle is lost as soon as you lose the Suzerain status.
>
> - Alliances
>
> Having an Alliance provides points per turn depending on the level of Alliance. Again, points are awarded for each separate active Alliance.

You can lose favor through inflicting too many grievances on other civilizations, also new to the expansion, and through emitting too much CO2, also new to the expansion.

Comment: Thank you for the description really great to find out what it means finally!

Comment: Hi @Dami, welcome to the website! If this answer helped you out, please mark it as accepted by clicking the little checkbox to the left of the answer :) This helps everyone know that your question has been answered to your satisfaction!